# Never-ending warnings about partial argument match

Tags: r, tidyr

I am constantly getting warnings about partial argument matches at times when it doesn't seem appropriate.  For instance, the below code when there are NO arguments:

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
x <- structure(list(unitid = 100654, year = 2006, state_of_residence_when_student_was_first_admitted = "Alabama", 
                    state_of_residence_original_line_number_on_survey_form = "Alabama", 
                    first_time_degree_certificate_seeking_undergraduate_students = 651, 
                    first_time_degree_certificate_seeking_undergraduate_students_who_graduated_from_high_school_in_the_past_12_months = 602), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))

x
#> # A tibble: 1 x 6
#>   unitid  year state_of_reside… state_of_reside… first_time_degr…
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            <chr>                       <dbl>
#> 1 100654  2006 Alabama          Alabama                       651
#> # ... with 1 more variable:
#> #   first_time_degree_certificate_seeking_undergraduate_students_who_graduated_from_high_school_in_the_past_12_months <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The warning that I get is:

```r
Warning messages:
1: In seq.default(along = x) :
partial argument match of 'along' to 'along.with'
2: In seq.default(along = x) :
partial argument match of 'along' to 'along.with'
```

[image]

And I get this all the time for various different code.  Does this happen to others? Is it a known issue with tidyverse (my searches yielded nothing). Or have I screwed something up in my settings that is causing this?

Comment: yeah it happens in a clean environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenny Bryan solved this for me.  It is a bug in R 3.5.1 which has been fixed, but the version with that fix has not been released yet.

See bug report here:
https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17449

Comment: I seem to have this issue for R 3.4.4 as well.  Thanks for following up on this once you figured it out.

Answer (score 4):

These *options* control the partial matching warnings:

- `warnPartialMatchArgs`: (`logical`) If `TRUE`, warns if partial matching is used in argument matching.
- `warnPartialMatchAttr`: (`logical`) If `TRUE`, warns if partial matching is used in extracting attributes via `attr`.
- `warnPartialMatchDollar`: (`logical`) If `TRUE`, warns if partial matching is used for extraction by `$`.

check if they're set and where they're set from and either disable it wholly or around the parts you just want to be less noisy.

Also ref: http://kevinushey.github.io/blog/2015/02/02/rprofile-essentials/

Comment: The thing is that I'm not giving it any arguments.  I want the warning when it's appropriate.